# Find out google custom search query parameter

Tags: google-custom-search

I am trying to connect google custom search with analytics and google wants me to to fill a query string. I am using 2 page look meaning that searchbox is separate from search results which are displayed on my page - /google-results. For example searching for term "product" the results are shown on page like so "/google-results?%3Fq%3D=product"
My question is - what is the query string here? And why is the parameter so "messy" instead of just ?q= (I specified it as a query parameter)
Thank you.